# Converting a dataframe of label/values to a named numeric vector

Tags: r

I am trying to convert a dataframe with labels/values to a named numeric vecotr.
For example I have the following dataframe

```
>df=data.frame(lab=c("A","B","C","D"),values=c(1,2,3,4))  
> df  
   lab values  
1   A      1  
2   B      2  
3   C      3  
4   D      4
```

So what I am trying to do is to iterate or use a function on this data frame to get the following

```
>v_needed=c("A"=1,"B"=2,"C"=3,"D"=4)  
> v_needed  
A B C D   
1 2 3 4
```

I tried to convert this to a factor but it didn't give the desired output

```
>v_failure=factor(df$values,labels=df$lab)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `setNames` function

```
v <- with(df, setNames(values, lab))
v
# A B C D 
# 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Thank you so much @MrFlick. What an easy solution!